# Error on grouping on a single element in the select list

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I have a query need (question really) that I would like to group the results by a value from a table with a where clause from another table.  The scenario looks like this:

Table1 (Single row for each description, no dupes)

- int id
- varchar(10) description (Single row for each description, no dupes)

Table2 multiple rows for each Table1.ID)

- int id
- fk_ref_tbl_1_ID (id from Table1)
- varchar(30) SomeText

Table3 (multiple rows for each Table2.ID)

- int id
- fk_ref_tbl_2_ID (id from Table2)
- varchar(30) ChoicesForTable2

The output I am desiring is something like this:

Table2.SomeText

- Table3.ChoicesForTable2
- Table3.ChoicesForTable2
- Table3.ChoicesForTable2

my query so far looks like this:

```
select Table2.Some, Table3.ChoicesForTable2 from Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2 on T1.id = T2.fk_ref_tbl_1_ID 
inner join Table3 t3 on T3.fk_ref_tbl_2_ID = T2.ID
where T1.id = 45
group by T2.id
```

I get an an error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Column 'T2.SomeText' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

without the group by I am getting something like this:

T2.SomeText, T3.ChoicesForTable2 (each T3.ChoicesForTable2  has a different value)
T2.SomeText, T3.ChoicesForTable2 (each T3.ChoicesForTable2  has a different value)
T2.SomeText, T3.ChoicesForTable2 (each T3.ChoicesForTable2  has a different value)
T2.SomeText, T3.ChoicesForTable2 (each T3.ChoicesForTable2  has a different value)
T2.SomeText, T3.ChoicesForTable2 (each T3.ChoicesForTable2  has a different value)

Think of Table1 as a Test, each test has many questions (Table2), and each question has several possible answers (Table3).  So ideally I would be able to generate a output where specific question is displayed and the possible choices right below it.  So my grouping would by the question (Table2)

I am really trying to do this all in T-SQL without cursors, I can brute force it with C# and then generate the test using SSRS, the more efficient way i think is to just come up with the right query to bind to the ssrs definition.  Since the real stumbling block for me here is the select with multiple fields and grouping, solving this will certainly ease the pain going forward.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You've done a great job describing your approach to your problem. We have a vague understanding of your table structure and what your error is. What will improve our ability to help you is real data. It doesn't have to be a complete dump, but enough so that we can understand your data. SQLFiddle.com is a great way to convey this + your table structure

Comment: Thanks for whoever reformatted the post, although I have lurked this site for years I have never posted to it until last night and couldn't figure out the formatting, sorry for the ugliness.